# raster r plot - log color scale in the raster plot function

Tags: r-raster

How do I make my color scale logarithmic using the plot function of raster package in R?

```
library(raster)

r <- raster("filename.nc")

plot(r, col=brewer.pal(9, "Reds"),zlim=c(1e-13,1e-10))
```

However, the scale is still linear and doesn't capture the whole range of numbers.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this?